# How can I interpret the following error graph?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am training a neural network which produces the following errors (epoch number on the x axis). I have some questions regrading interpreting it.

- When I say `model.predict` is it giving me the result based on the final state (that is epoch 5000)?
- Towards the end (and some places in the middle) there are places where the training error and validation error are farther apart. Does this mean that the model was over-fitting on those epochs?
- Based on the graph, can one determine that the model was `best` at a certain epoch?
- Does Keras have API methods to retrieve the model at a specific epoch so that I can retrieve the `best` model?

[image]

Comment: Somehow this looks like you are randomly initializing weights every epoch or your inputs are random

Comment: @DuttaA thank you for your comment. Can you please elaborate? Also looking at the train error,there is a wave like pattern. Would you not say that the wave like pattern indicates that the model is learning (that is it was performing best when the wave was at a minimum?)

Comment: My bad I did not ask what do you mean by error? Is it loss or prediction error?

Comment: @DuttaA loss, as drawn in this example https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression, although the data is not the same. I just took the graph code from there

Comment: do you do measures agains over-fitting or maybe reduce leraning rate with the time?

Comment: @user8426627 I use Adam optimizer and I use Dropout

Comment: thats weird because even train error dont converge. Make learning rate smaller and try to run over small amount of epochs

Comment: @user8426627 thanks for the suggestion. I will try that